# django-modelform can't bind post data

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a problem with `django modelform`

here is the model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    content=models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

here is the modelForm:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
```

in the view:

```
def comment(request):
    response = HttpResponse()   

    f = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        comment = f.save(commit=False)
        response.write("1")
    else:
        response.write("0")

return response
```

form in templates:

```
<form action="/comment/add/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"></p>
    <p>Your e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Content: <textarea name="content" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

the problem is `f.is_valid()` is always `False`.
but if i define a dict like this:

```
data={
        'username':'test',
        'email':'test@test.com',
        'content':'test comment'
    }
```

and put it in the modelform: `f = CommentForm(data)` after this, `f.is_valid()` will be `True` 
i don't know why,anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `method="POST"` attribute in `<form>` tag. And make sure you put `{% csrf_token %}` is within your form.

Comment: thx your answer. i'm sure i add all of that. and in the view, the request.POST has values (QueryDict). it looks like CommentForm(request.POST) not worked.

Comment: check `request.POST` by adding `print request.POST` within your function. Watch in console. If necessary, try, for example, `print request.POST['username']`

Comment: my gtalk: addaraquthny